# How to replace "times" with "time" depending on the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
total = [0]
one = 0
two = 0
three = 0
four = 0
five = 0
six = 0

dice=True
while dice:
a = random.randrange(1,7)
if a == 1:
    one = one + 1
elif a == 2:
    two = two + 1
elif a == 3:
    three = three + 1
elif a == 4:
    four = four + 1
elif a == 5:
    five = five + 1
elif a == 6:
    six = six + 1


b = len(total)
print ("Roll:", b,)
print ("The dice has rolled:",a,)
total.append (a)




dice =input("Roll again? (y,n):")
if dice == "n":
    print ("Thank-You!")
    print ("One rolled",one,"times")
    print ("Two rolled",two,"times")
    print ("Three rolled",three,"times")
    print ("Four rolled",four,"times")
    print ("Five rolled",five,"times")
    print ("Six rolled",six,"times")

    break
```

How can I make it so that if "one" has only been rolled "once" it says "one has been rolled time" instead of "one has been rolled 1 times"?

Thanks. An explanation would also be good so that I can learn

Comment: It's really simple. `if one == 1: print("One rolled 1 time.") else: print("One rolled", one, "times")`

Comment: Can you honestly not even think of a way to *start* this?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem thanks, I thought of that but just did it a little wrong..Is there a way to do it just once so that the code isn't cluttered with lots of if statements for one-six?

Comment: It's often acceptable to use `time(s)` to avoid making the distinction between singular and plural.

Comment: @potatomeister Yes there is. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function called `printTimesRolled` or something similar. Then pass a string, and an int. Like this:

```
def printTimesRolled(numberWord, timesRolled):
    if (timesRolled == 1):
        print(numberWord, "rolled 1 time.")
    else:
        print(numberWord, "rolled", timesRolled, "times.")
```

Then, to print them all, just do this:

```
printTimesRolled("One", one)
printTimesRolled("Two", two)
...
```

Comment: thanks bro :D. This helped with learning functions which is the next topic :D.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.format` and a check whether the number has been rolled exactly one time. Demo:

```
>>> one = 1
>>> 'One rolled {} time{}'.format(one, 's' if one!=1 else '')
'One rolled 1 time'
>>> one = 0
>>> 'One rolled {} time{}'.format(one, 's' if one!=1 else '')
'One rolled 0 times'
>>> one = 3
>>> 'One rolled {} time{}'.format(one, 's' if one!=1 else '')
'One rolled 3 times'
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good way to handle the dice rolling. I am not sure if you have started exploring classes yet, but by making the DiceRoller class you make it slightly more organized. Besides, you avoid tons of global variables.

Using a dictionary for comparisons will allow you to run a for loop to compare it, rahter than having 6 elif statements, making the code more efficient.

Finally, when the user types "n" to quit and check on his rolls, we compare to `again.lower()` to failsafe it in case the user types "N" instead.

Then it loops through the dictionary and prints 'time / roll' or 'times / rolls' based on a simple if statement.

I hope this makes sense to you, if not just ask!

```
import random

# DEFINING THE CLASS
class DiceRoller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sides = {1:0,
                      2:0,
                      3:0,
                      4:0,
                      5:0,
                      6:0}

    # WILL ROLL THE DICE AND ADD 1 TO THE SIDE COUNTER WHEN A SIDE IS ROLLED
    def rollTheDice(self):
        roll = random.randint(1,6)

        for side in (self.sides):
            if roll == side:
                self.sides[side] += 1

        print('Rolled a %s' % (roll))

    # WILL PRINT TOTAL ROLLS WHEN CALLED
    def getTotals(self):
        for i, side in enumerate(self.sides):
            if self.sides[side] == 1:
                print('Side %s: %s roll' % (i + 1, self.sides[side]))
            else:
                print('Side %s: %s rolls' % (i + 1, self.sides[side]))


# THIS CODE IS EXECUTED
Dice = DiceRoller()

while True:
    Dice.rollTheDice()
    again = input('Roll again [y/n]: ')

    if again.lower() == 'n':
        break

Dice.getTotals()
```

This code outputs the following when run a couple of times:

```
Rolled a 2
Roll again [y/n]: y
Rolled a 4
Roll again [y/n]: y
Rolled a 3
Roll again [y/n]: y
Rolled a 1
Roll again [y/n]: y
Rolled a 4
Roll again [y/n]: y
Rolled a 2
Roll again [y/n]: n
Side 1: 1 roll
Side 2: 2 rolls
Side 3: 1 roll
Side 4: 2 rolls
Side 5: 0 rolls
Side 6: 0 rolls

Process finished with exit code 0
```